# Some threads dont stop with Gmap when i close the application

Tags: c#, multithreading, gmap.net

I started using Gmaps for C# and i noticed that sometimes when i run the program in debug mode and i exit it, there are still some Gmap threads that keep running (i am assuming that this is whats happening) so the program doesnt finish executing and i need to press stop debuging. I really dont want that this would keep happening later when the program is finished.

So is there any way to force the threads to close within the GMapControl or is something else going on?

```
  public class GoogleMap : GMapControl
  {
        public GoogleMap() : base ()
        {
              this.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap;
              this.Position = new PointLatLng(46.6682870738831, 15.9823608398438);
              this.MinZoom = 1;
              this.MaxZoom = 17;
              this.Zoom = 9;
              this.Location = new Point(0, 24);
              this.DragButton = MouseButtons.Left;
              originalWidth = Obj.mainForm.ClientRectangle.Width;
              originalHeight = Obj.mainForm.ClientRectangle.Height;
              this.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
  }
```

This is the constructor that i use and then i just add the GoogleMap object to my main form with

```
GoogleMap map = new GoogleMap();
this.Controls.Add(map);
```

Comment: Haven`t used Gmap myself but it seems that you are not disposing resources correctly. Does GoogleMap class implement IDisposable pattern?

Comment: Yes i tryed using .Dispose() it still keeps happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's background caching, it will stop after few minutes, if you want exit immediately, call on exit `map.Manager.CancelTileCaching();`